# Running two Jboss instances of different versions simultaneously

Tags: jboss, multiple-instances

My application is scaled across two jboss versions Jboss 4 and Jboss 7. Jboss 4 intance is running through eclipse. When I try to run Jboss 7 throught [JBOSS_HOME]/bin/standalone.bat it doesn't start and shows the below error.

Calling "C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\bin\standalone.conf.bat"
WARNING JBOSS_HOME may be pointing to a different installation - unpredictable results may occur.
Could not locate "C:\jboss\jboss-eap-4.3\jboss-as\jboss-modules.jar".
Please check that you are in the bin directory when running this script.
Press any key to continue . . .

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is resolved by configuring Jboss 7 via jboss developer studio plugin in eclipse. web ports of both Jboss 4 and Jboss 7 should be different as shown in the below screenshot.

http://postimg.org/image/a6782xcoj/

Answer (score 1):

standalone.bat tries to check if JBOSS_HOME variable is set and if not it tries to set it.

```
if "x%JBOSS_HOME%" == "x" (
set "JBOSS_HOME=%RESOLVED_JBOSS_HOME%"
)
```

Jboss 7 requires  jboss-modules.jar which is located under jboss directory. 
In your case it appears that JBoss 4 is already setting JBOSS_HOME to "C:\jboss\jboss-eap-4.3\jboss-as\". This is causin the problem.

Comment: That is what might be happening but how it could be fixed?

Comment: try changing the name of variable JBOSS_HOME to JBOSS_HOME_7 in all the occurrences in jboss/bin of your Jboss 7. I have not tested it but this may resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to test running your code in JBoss 4 and JBoss 7 and having them talk to simulate the server environment then you may want to set up VMs locally.  That would be closer to what you will have when they are deployed.